# Finding a line that shows in a file only once

Tags: linux, bash, file

Assuming that I have files with 100 lines. There are a lot of lines that repeat themselves in the file, and only one line that does not.

I want to find the line that shows only once. Is there a command for that or do I have to build some complicated loop as below?

My code so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
filename="repeat_lines.txt"

var="$(wc -l <$filename )"
echo "length:" $var
#cp ex4.txt ex4_copy.txt
for((index=0; index < var; index++));
do
    one="$(head -n $index $filename | tail -1)"
    counter=0
        for((index2=0; index2 < var; index2++));
        do
            two="$(head -n $index2 $filename | tail -1)"
            if [ "$one" == "$two" ]; then
                counter=$((counter+1))
            fi
        done
    echo $one"is "$counter" times in the text: "
done
```

Answer (score 6):

If I understood your question correctly, then

`sort repeat_lines.txt | uniq -u` should do the trick.

e.g. for file containing:

```
a
b
a
c
b
```

it will output `c`.

For further reference, see [sort manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sort), [uniq manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/uniq).

Answer (score 1):

You've got a reasonable answer that uses standard shell tools `sort` and `uniq`. That's probably the solution you want to use, if you want something that is portable and doesn't require `bash`.

But an alternative would be to use functionality built into your `bash` shell. One method might be to use an associative array, which is a feature of bash 4 and above.

```
$ cat file.txt
a
b
c
a
b
$ declare -A lines
$ while read -r x; do ((lines[$x]++)); done < file.txt
$ for x in "${!lines[@]}"; do [[ ${lines["$x"]} -gt 1 ]] && unset lines["$x"]; done
$ declare -p lines
declare -A lines='([c]="1" )'
```

What we're doing here is:

1. `declare -A` creates the associative array. This is the bash 4 feature I mentioned.
2. The `while` loop reads each line of the file, and increments a counter that uses the content of a line of the file as the key in the associative array.
3. The `for` loop steps through the array, deleting any element whose counter is greater than 1.
4. `declare -p` prints the details of an array in a predictable, re-usable format. You could alternately use another `for` loop to step through the remaining array elements (of which there might be only one) in order to do something with them.

Note that this solution, while fine for small files (say, up to a few thousand lines), may not scale well for very large files of, say, millions of lines. Bash isn't the fastest at reading input this way, and one must be cognizant of memory limits when using arrays.

The `sort` alternative has the benefit of memory optimization using files on disk for extremely large files, at the expense of speed.

If you're dealing with files of only a few hundred lines, then it's hard to predict which solution will be faster. In the end, the form of output may dictate your choice of solution. The `sort | uniq` pipe generates a list to standard output. The bash solution above generates the same list as keys in an array. Otherwise, they are functionally equivalent.